# python DataFrame comparison using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have 5 dataframes. They have same columns but they have different values.
I want to print the highest value in column 3 among 5. What should I do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no attempt to solve whatsoever by user.

Answer (score 1):

df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 can be the five dataframes. You want the max of the 3rd column. First make a list of the max of the third column in each of the dataframes, then find the max of the list.

```
data = [ df1[[3]].max(), df2[[3]].max(), df3[[3]].max(), df4[[3]].max(), df5[[3]].max() ]
print(max(data))
```

or using a loop

```
dfList = [ df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 ]
maxList = []
for df in dfList:
    maxList.append(df[[3]].max())
print(max(maxList))
```

Comment: Thanks but code returned an error "  f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). "

Comment: Could you put in an example of the 5 dataframes so I could see what is going on?

Comment: I pull data from sql for dataframes.Dataframes are like these  and I want to print the highest deger value among 5 dataframe where id is 2 for example

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/Fx4VP9

Comment: Doesn't look like there should be a problem.  but there is...  `df1.iloc[ : , 2 ]` will also get the third column so you could try `maxList.append(df.iloc[:,2].max())` in the loop.  Also, you could try. max(numeric_only=True) to make sure there are no non-numeric items in the max() functions.

Answer (score 0):

Bit expensive but a oneliner could be:

```
pd.concat([df1.col3,df2.col3,df3.col3,df4.col3,df5.col3]).max()
```

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1],'col2': [2],'col3': [5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1],'col2': [2],'col3': [10]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1],'col2': [2],'col3': [12]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1],'col2': [2],'col3': [15]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,10],'col2': [2,12],'col3': [19,13]})
```

Output of the code:

```
19
```